# Nenhuma tradução para a mensagem "Sem postagens" nos perfis de usuário

Tags: bug, status-pronto, tradução

Quero ver qualquer perfil de usuário sem postagens e vejo isso:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Acho que deveria haver tradução do "Este usuário ainda não postou".

Perfil de exemplo com este problema: [Comunidade (Bot)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/-1/comunidade).

Acho que você precisa traduzir essa string.

Comment: A cada build do site muitas vezes temos que traduzir novamente, é o processo que temos por enquanto e também parece que algumas strings não estão disponíveis para tradução (parece ser o caso dessa, irei confirmar).

Comment: String atualizada: https://pt.traducir.win/strings/15248, é preciso aguardar o processo, que toma algum tempo - Sugestões de outras correções podem ser enviadas diretamente no https://pt.traducir.win/. Observe que a cada novo build dos sites as vezes precisamos traduzir novamente.